# Can I add/remove class on element loaded by load() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navbar with class called "active" with some CSS styling. The navbar is used on a number of subpages so I figured out that instead of repeating the code on all the subpages I will load navbar with `load()` function.

The problem is that with the content loaded by the `load()` function I cannot remove the class using `removeClass()`. The navbar is loaded, I can see the tags in inspector, and all seems to be OK. The code is working if I put the navbar manually in the HTML.

I've tried to move the `script` tag that deletes the class after the CDN script, but it does not help (the idea was to remove class on the fully loaded page). What am I missing?

I'm using the following code to load the navbar:

```
$(function(){
  $("#includeNavbar").load("../partials/navbar.html"); 
});
```

Then I put a tag in HTML:

```
<div id="includeNavbar"></div>
```

Then I use `<script>` tag in the HTML, but below code does not remove class:

```
<script>
  $("li").removeClass("active");
  $("li").eq(1).addClass("active");             
</script>
```

Comment: `.load()` is asynchronous so odds are that your add/removeClass is being executed prior to the load completing. Try instead to use loads()'s callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is where you're calling `removeClass()` and `addClass()` from. You need to do it in the callback of the `load()`, to ensure that the content exists in the DOM when you execute those calls:

```
$(function(){
  $("#includeNavbar").load("../partials/navbar.html", function() {
    $("li").removeClass("active").eq(1).addClass("active");
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I changed first() to eq(1), as I was aiming for the second element (second() didn't work). Can you tell me why you chosen first() instead of eq()?

Comment: Sorry - `first()` was my bad, I misread the code :) Glad you got it working though